# How to use SET FILTER TO in FoxPro to limit the results to matched records in another cursor

Tags: foxpro, dbf, visual-foxpro

Say, I've got a cursor with data records, with an identifying foreign key in `csrData`:

```
|  ID  |  Foreign_ID  |  
|  1   |  1           |  
|  2   |  1           |  
|  3   |  2           |  
|  4   |  2           |  
|  5   |  2           |  
|  6   |  3           |
```

And a list of foreign IDs in a separate cursor `csrMatches`:

```
|  Match_Foreign_ID  |  
|  1                 |  
|  3                 |
```

Is there a SET FILTER TO command I can issue against `csrData` to get:

```
|  ID  |  Foreign_ID  |  
|  1   |  1           |  
|  2   |  1           |  
|  6   |  3           |
```

I know this can be achieved using a SQL query, but the reporting framework I'm using limits me to `SET FILTER TO` statements.  The `INLIST()` function works similarly, but I'd like to do filtering against a set of unknown size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a filter condition that will look up a given `csrData.Foreign_ID` in `csrMatches` and return true if it's found, false otherwise.

First, create an index on the `Match_Foreign_ID` field in `csrMatches`.  Then, create a filter that uses `indexseek()` to test each `Foreign_ID` for inclusion in csrMatches.

```
select csrMatches
index on Match_Foreign_ID tag Foreign_ID

select csrData
set filter to indexseek(csrData.Foreign_ID, .f., "csrMatches", "Foreign_ID")
```

Using [`indexseek()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5x9ftb1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is slightly faster than [`seek()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9143x601%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) because `indexseek()` simply uses the index to check if the key is found, and does not move the active record pointer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an index on each "cursor", you could do it via set relation, set filter...

If you created the cursors via SELECT ... INTO CURSOR csrData, be sure to add the keyword "READWRITE" to allow a read-writable cursor that you can build index tags on..

```
select ... from ... where ... into cursor csrData READWRITE
```

same with csrMatches -- READWRITE.

Once created, do the following...

```
select csrMatches
index on Match_Foreign_ID tag Foreign_ID

select csrData
set relation to Foreign_ID into csrMatches

set filter to NOT EOF( "csrMatches" )
```

since the data is related INTO the other matches table, whenever the record pointer moves from one row to the other, it tries to find a match for you in the "related" cursor (or table).  If it can't find one, that other cursor, it moves the other cursor to EOF() (end of file).  So now, you can set filter to NOT EOF( "csrMatches" )

One additional advantage of this approach, is you can also filter on VALUES of columns IN the other table too... if you ever needed to.  Such as if you were linking sales to customers table and wanted to show based on a customer's based on certain state or region.  Of course, all sales would be associated to a customer, but you could apply the filter via

```
select customers
set index to customerID

select SalesSample
set relation to customerID into customers

set filter for not eof( "Customers" ) and inlist( Customers.State, "NY, "PA", "MA" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join these two cursors together using a select statement.

SELECT * FROM csrData INNER JOIN csrMatches ON ID = Match_Foreign_ID INTO CURSOR cresults NOFILTER

Comment: The framework I'm using requires me to use `SET FILTER TO`. As the question states, I know this is easily accomplished with a SQL query.